# Gerar um Partial Model a partir de um Model completo

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

Tenho uma `Model` chamado: `Cliente_man` que representa o cadastro de clientes.

Porém este `Model`, tem muitas informações, e para a tela que estou desenvolvendo não ah necessidade de todas, então gostaria de passar para a `View` um `Partial Model` somente com os dados que eu preciso usar.

Segue abaixo parte do código recebendo o `Model` completo(`Cliente_Man`)

`Controller`:

```
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult DetailTabControl()
    {
        if (Session["cod_cli"] != null)
        {
            int codCliente = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["codCliente"]);

            Cliente_man model = db.Cliente_man.Find(codCliente);

            return PartialView("~/Views/Cliente_man/_DetailTabControl.cshtml", model);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
    }
```

`View`:

```
@model OneeWeb_v3.Models.Crm.Cliente_man
<h3>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.razao_social).ToHtmlString()
</h3>
```

Então, criei um novo `Model` chamado: `Cliente_manDetalhes`, que contem somente os dados que eu preciso.

Alterei na `View`:

```
@model OneeWeb_v3.Models.Crm.Cliente_manDetalhes
<h3>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.razao_social).ToHtmlString()
</h3>
```

E no `Controller`:

```
 [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult DetailTabControl()
    {
        if (Session["cod_cli"] != null)
        {
            int codCliente = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["codCliente"]);

            //Cliente_man model = db.Cliente_man.Find(codCliente);

            Cliente_manDetalhes mode = from s in db.Cliente_man
                                       where s.id_cliente == codCliente
                                       select new
                                       {
                                           id_cliente = s.id_cliente,
                                           nome_fantasia = s.nome_fantasia,
                                           Perfil = s.Perfil,
                                           n_doc = s.n_doc,
                                           cidade = s.cidade,
                                           siglaEstado = s.siglaEstado
                                       });

            return PartialView("~/Views/Cliente_man/_DetailTabControl.cshtml", model);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
    }
```

Porém como faço para recuperar as informações do `Model` `Cliente_Man`? Ao o código acima retorna o erro:

`Cannot implicity convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<<anonymous type:int id_cliente, string nome_fantasia, string Perfil, string n_doc, string cidade, string siglaEstado>>' to 'OneeWeb_v3.Models.Crm.Cliente_manDetalhes'. An explicit conversion exists`

Comment: esse Cliente_manDetalhes  'e o mesmo que Cliente_man ? a sua query retorna os valores para esse modulo de forma correta? se sim apenas coloque (esse Cliente_manDetalhes) na frente da query

Comment: Thomas, por favor, sempre adicione as mensagens de erro como texto e não como imagens. Além de facilitar a leitura e a melhorar a indexação da pergunta, evita de que pessoas com bloqueios a domínios externos não consigam ler toda a publicação.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem vários erros aí.

Pra começar. Esta consulta

```
from s in db.Cliente_man
where s.id_cliente == codCliente
select new
{
    id_cliente = s.id_cliente,
    nome_fantasia = s.nome_fantasia,
    Perfil = s.Perfil,
    n_doc = s.n_doc,
    cidade = s.cidade,
    siglaEstado = s.siglaEstado
});
```

retorna uma lista de objetos de um tipo anônimo, uma vez que você usou a *keyword* `new` e não especificou o tipo a ser criado.

Você está tentado atribuir o resultado da consulta a uma variável do tipo `Cliente_manDetalhes`.

Seria possível adaptar a consulta para retornar uma lista de `Cliente_manDetalhes`, alterando a instrução `select` para

```
select new Cliente_manDetalhes { ... }
```

A atribuição continuaria errada porque o retorno disso será uma coleção de `Cliente_manDetalhes` e, além disso, o EF não conseguiria criar instâncias de 
`Cliente_manDetalhes`.

Bem, a solução é simples, você precisa materializar os dados antes de tentar fazer o mapeamento para `Cliente_manDetalhes`.

Como você precisa de um item e não de uma coleção, pode facilitar a sua consulta usando `First`/`FirstOrDefault`, mas precisaria fazer este mapeamento de outra forma que não usando o método `Select`.

```
var item = db.Cliente_man.FirstOrDefault(s => s.id_cliente == codCliente);
var mode = new Cliente_manDetalhes
{
    id_cliente = item.id_cliente,
    nome_fantasia = item.nome_fantasia,
    Perfil = item.Perfil,
    n_doc = item.n_doc,
    cidade = item.cidade,
    siglaEstado = item.siglaEstado
};
```

Se você fizer questão de usar o método `Select` para isso, vai precisar adaptar sua consulta. Seria algo como:

```
(from s in db.Cliente_man
where s.id_cliente == codCliente 
select s)  // #1 Consulta LINQ To Entities - Retorna uma lista de Cliente_man
.ToArray() // #2 Materialização da consulta em memória
.Select(s => new Cliente_manDetalhes
{
    ... // #3 Mapeamento da lista de Cliente_man para Cliente_manDetalhes
})
.FirstOrDefault(); #4 // Seleção do primeiro item
```